# Is mathematical proof itself NP-hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, complexity-classes, proof-complexity

At the 8:00 mark of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YX40hbAHx3s), he claims that proving things is itself an NP problem. I'm looking for more insight into this. Could someone help explain this concept to me and also provide a link to some further reading? I'm trying to get a better understanding of the relationships between complexity classes.

Comment: Since this has been downvoted twice, could someone please explain what I need to do in order to make this a valid question? I realize this site is more for research level questions, but it didn't seem appropriate on math.se

Comment: The most appropriate place is probably https://cs.stackexchange.com. In any case, it's a subtle question because it depends on your definition of "proof". For example, in some cases, it's not hard to construct (via diagonalization) a sequence of statements such that the length of the shortest proof of those statements grows extremely quickly (as fast as any time-constructable function) as a function of the number of symbols in the statement. If you're familiar with the halting problem, try showing a length lower bound on statements like "Turing Machine X does not halt within 2^2^2^|<X>| steps"

Comment: @YonatanN I see how it's possible to theoretically construct a problem that requires an absurdly long proof, but I don't have enough experience yet to have a grasp on bounding a problem like the one you presented. I assume that in the context of the video I linked, the creator is suggesting that an algorithm confirming the validity of a proof of P vs NP would necessarily be NP, but I don't currently have intuition on a statement like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to some lecture notes that answer my question - [http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~sabhar/publications/iaspcmi-proofcomplexity00.pdf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Esabhar/publications/iaspcmi-proofcomplexity00.pdf)

Proof complexity is a vast field of mathematics.